# How to access service from virtual machine of another machine in local network?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I have two Ubuntu machines A and B in my local network.

Computer B has an openmediavault instance set up via KVM.

Computer B has the IP address 192.168.177.58, the openmediavault instance provides a service that I can access in the browser at the address http://192.168.122.153:3670 .

I cannot access this address in A's browser; but I can do so in B's browser.

How can I access the service of the openmediavault instance from A's browser?

This is the setup of my network:

[image]

in the console of computer B, I can see:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

In the console of computer A, it shows:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3389/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3389/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The output for machine A for `ip r` is:

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.177.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.7.0/24 dev vmnet1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.1 
192.168.95.0/24 dev vmnet8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.95.1 
192.168.177.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.177.21 metric 600
```

and for machine B:

```
$ ip r
default via 192.168.177.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 
192.168.177.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.177.70 metric 100
```

I can see the following settings in the network part of KVM:

[image]

[image]

and could add a new network adapter, but I am unsure whether this would help:

[image]

[image]

The output of `ip addr show` on A:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:b7:53:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:2a:ea:b6:41:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.177.21/24 brd 192.168.177.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 846831sec preferred_lft 846831sec
    inet6 fe80::ea2a:eaff:feb6:41bc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.1/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.95.1/24 brd 192.168.95.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The output of `ip addr show` on B:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:ae:dd:0f:f3:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.177.70/24 brd 192.168.177.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 797182sec preferred_lft 797182sec
    inet6 fe80::42ea:dead:571a:66aa/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp0s20f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:9e:94:e2:f5:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:db:9f:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:85:b6:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: vnet13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:e4:1b:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fee4:1b11/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

According to its routing table, the only way for 'A' to access 192.168.122.0/24 is via the default route (192.168.177.1). Presumably the default router does not have a route for 192.168.122.0/24

I can't tell you how to fix this because you haven't provided any details of how the physical networks align to the IP subnets.

A really ugly (and dangerous) hack would be to enable routing on B and add a route on A to 192.168.122.0/24 via 192.168.177.58

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. Could you perhaps tell me how I could provide you the details about the alignment between the physical networks and the IP subnets (your second sentence)? I would amend my question afterwards. And apart from that: how would I enable routing on B to add the route on A (... your last sentence)? (I am unfortunately not experienced at all with all these topics until now). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need a list or diagram showing where all the interfaces (both virtual and physical) are attached to ip sub-nets / physical networks.

Comment: I amended my post with the output of `ip addr show`. If this is not what you meant: could you please tell me which command I have to put in a (bash) shell so that I could deliver to you what you are requesting? Thanks in advance! (as mentioned: I am an absolute beginner with regards to networking topics...)

Comment: Doesn't tell me the connections between the virtual NICs and brodges not between physical ports and bridges

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of doing such a thing is to have one central router that can access all of those networks, you could add a firewall/router into the network that is aware of all the subnets and is able to route the traffic into the required network.
If your modem/router allows it you can add additional IP's to it.

But if this is just a simple home situation and you don't care too much about isolation then why not just add them into the same network?

The problem is the NAT network, just make it a bridge network directly into your network.
KVM hypervisors usually have a bridge interface on which the other networks are connected.
First hit on google: [Bridge things](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-bridged-networking-with-libvirt-and-kvm)

Or if you just want to have it running quick 'n dirty why not pass the webserver port over SSH via localforwarding:
[SSH localforwarding](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example)